# Separation of singing voice from music

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to know how to perform "spectral change detection" for the classification of vocal & non-vocal segments of a song. We need to find the spectral changes from a spectrogram.  Any elaborate information about this, particularly involving MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

Separating out distinct signals from audio is a very active area of research, and it is a very hard problem.  This is often called [Blind Signal Separation](http://www.tsi.enst.fr/~cardoso/guidesepsou.html) in the literature. (There is some MATLAB demo code in the previous link.

Of course, if you know that there is vocal in the music, you can use one of the many [vocal separation](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=vocal+separation+algorithm) algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, solving this problem using only raw spectrum analysis is a dauntingly hard problem, and you're unlikely to find a good solution to it.  At best, you might be able to extract some of the vocals and a few extra crossover frequencies from the mix.

However, if you can be more specific about the nature of the audio material you are working with here, you might be able to get a little bit further.

In the worst case, your material would be normal mp3's of regular songs -- ie, a full band + vocalist.  I have a feeling that this is the case you are probably looking at given the nature of your question.

In the best case, you have access to the multitrack studio recordings and have at least a full mixdown and an instrumental track, in which case you could extract the vocal frequencies from the mix.  You would do this by generating an impulse response from one of the tracks and applying it to the other.

In the middle case, you are dealing with simple music which you could apply some sort of algorithm tuned to the parameters of the music to.  For instance, if you are dealing with electronic music, you can use to your advantage the stereo width of the track to eliminate all mono elements (ie, basslines + kicks) to extract the vocals + other panned instruments, and then apply some type of filtering and spectrum analysis from there.

In short, if you are planning on making an all-purpose algorithm to generate clean acapella cuts from arbitrary source material, you're probably biting off more than you can chew here.  If you can specifically limit your source material, then you have a number of algorithms at your disposal depending on the nature of those sources.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard. If you can do this reliably you will be an accomplished computer scientist. The most promising method I read about used the lyrics to generate a voice only track for comparison. Again, if you can do this and write a paper about it you will be famous (amongst computer scientists). Plus you could make a lot of money by automatically generating timings for karaoke.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to decide wether a block of music is clean a-capella or with instrumental background, you could probably do that by comparing the bandwidth of the signal to a normal human singer bandwidth. Also, you could check for the base frequency, which can only be in a pretty limited frequency range for human voices.

Still, it probably won't be easy. However, hearing aids do this all the time, so it is clearly doable. (Though they typically search for speech, not singing)

Answer (score -1):

first sync the instrumental with the original, make sure they are the same length and bitrate and start and end at the exact time and convert them to .wav

then do something like

```
I = wavread(instrumental.wav);
N = wavread(normal.wav);
i = inv(I);
A = (N - i); // it could be A = (N * i) or A = (N + i) you'll have to play around
wavwrite(A, acapella.wav)
```

that should do it.. a little linear algebra goes a long way.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. He is asking about "spectral change detection"; your taking the difference of two wavs does not answer his question.